# how to configure redis slave-slave configuration

Tags: redis

I am new to redis , I configured redis master-slave configuration, but i want to configure slave-slave configuration so that data will be in sync with across all the slave systems. Any suggestions would be appreciated .

Comment: You just need to set `slaveof` on another slave.  The slave will be slave to the master, not slave to another slave.  Why would you want/need it to slave off of a slave anyway?

Comment: i am designing the setup now, Currently i have 4 EC2 instances ,2 each on different zones. I want to setup redis servers associated with these 4 instances so that all the redis instances can SYNC each other.

Comment: @Manjunath Bavihal, Let me know if you find the answer